# Хочу написать бота, который при вступление кем то в чат, будет писать ему правила

Tags: telebot

Но не знаю как сделать, чтобы бот получал сигнал о вступление в чат юсером. Пишу на pytelegrambotapi

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `content_types=['new_chat_members']`. [отсюда](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/532#issuecomment-404019969)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'добро пожаловать в чат')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def any_msg(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Рады приветствовать Вас! Тут Вы пишите правила')
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: ["text"] - здесь можете написать start, то есть при входе в бота, автоматически на команду start бот отправит ему сообщение, правило.

Comment: Вы меня немного не правильно поняли. Я хочу сделать бота для общего чата, а не для чата юзера с ботом

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно что бы он с самого начала работы выводил какое-либо сообщение, если конечно он не многопользовательский...

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы когда юсер заходит в общий чат, он писал сообщение

Comment: Вы же берете у @BotFather токен, там в настройках можно сделать такое автоматическое сообщение, которое отображается, даже когда Вы не написали ничего. У BotGather, где Вы ставите фотку на бота, там и будет среди всех функций нужная Вам